# Какую БД лучше использовать для ТГ бота?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Делаю добавление юзера в БД. Вопрос, не крашнется ли у меня программа если одновременно в неё будет добавляться несколько юзеров? Если что юзаю Sqlite. И ещё я где-то слышал, что sqlite - принципиально однопользовательская БД и с ней нельзя работать из нескольких потоков/процессов. Какую лучше БД использовать для ТГ бота?

```
    public async Task<int> AddUserAsync(int userId, string userName)
    {
        User user = new User { UserId = userId, UserName = userName };
        await using(var db = new TelegramBotDBContext())
        {
            if(!await db.Users.AnyAsync(u=>u.UserId == userId))
            {
                _ = await db.Users.AddAsync(user);
                return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `sqlite` - это встраиваемая БД, преджназначенная для одного клиента. По сути это файл просто на вашем жестком диске. Если у вас будет 5-10-100 юзеров, то вы можете их регистрировать в ней. Если же вы планируете более серьезный подход, заказать хостинг для бота, открыть бота всему миру, чтобы набрать максимум пользователей (например, тысяч 100  и более), которые постоянно будут что то писать в чаты, организовать бекапы данных и тд, то вам наверное лучше поискать более выносливую БД, типа MariaDB или PostgreSQL

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо за ответ)